# How do I start react serve in Development mode?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, server, build, serve

So, I have a React app, which is live on production using `serve`.

These are the commands I've used for doing so:

```
NODE_ENV=production react-scripts build

NODE_ENV=production serve -s build
```

So that's production done!
But now I want to do the same thing on the development server.
I've tried this:

```
NODE_ENV=development react-scripts build

NODE_ENV=development serve -s build
```

But that still compiles as the production build, and even `serve` starts on production mode.

How can I build and run using `react-scripts` & `serve` on development mode?

---

### I don't want to:

1. Run via `npm run start`, since that crashes my server (by consuming a lot of resources while compiling)
2. Use `dotenv` for setting environment variables, since that's third-party.

Comment: I later used custom envs like: `REACT_APP_ENV=development` for doing this, still looking for the solution with `NODE_ENV`.